# How can I increment a number in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a button that will increment a number in Firestore when pressed. I'm using onclick on my button to call the function (called vote1). I tried to use the Fireship tutorial on how to use Firestore Incremement, but when I try it, I only get this error code:

```
Uncaught TypeError: valg1.update is not a function
    at vote1 (index.js:316)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick
```

This is the code I use:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);

function vote1() {
  console.log('ans1');

  const valg1 = db.collection('spørsmål').doc().collection('valg1');
  valg1.update({ 'valg1': increment });
}
```

The field in Firestore I am trying to increase is called "valg1". What is the easiest way to increase the number in Firestore when the button is pressed?

Comment: Put 'valg1' inside of.doc() and remove.collection. Then let me know what it does. :)

Comment: When I tried that I just got a long error starting with: "FirebaseError: No document to update". Is that because of the document ID is made by firebase and the field is in the document?

Comment: @JoelHager I tried adding the document uid in .doc() and now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only update fields inside a document:

```
  const valg1 = db.collection('spørsmål').doc('documentName');
  valg1.update({ 'valg1': increment });
```